# Error converting static Swift Array in Enum to NSArray

Tags: arrays, swift, enums, nsarray

As far as I understand, an `Array` in Swift will be automatically casted to `NSArray` if necessary.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html 
says on that account

> „When you bridge from an NSArray object to a Swift array, the resulting array is of type AnyObject[]. An object is AnyObject compatible if it is an instance of an Objective-C or Swift class, or if the object can be bridged to one. You can bridge any NSArray object to a Swift array because all Objective-C objects are AnyObject compatible. Because all NSArray objects can be bridged to Swift arrays, the Swift compiler replaces the NSArray class with AnyObject[] when it imports Objective-C APIs.“

Auszug aus: Apple Inc. „Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.“ iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/de/book/using-swift-cocoa-objective/id888894773?mt=11

In my Playground the following fails with

> [Position] is not convertible to 'NSArray'

```
import Foundation

enum Position : String {
    case TopLeft = "Top Left", TopCenter = "Top Center", TopRight = "Top Right", BottomLeft = "Bottom Left", BottomCenter = "Bottom Center", BottomRight = "Bottom Right"
    // pattern to iterate enums by http://www.swift-studies.com/blog/2014/6/10/enumerating-enums-in-swift
    static let allValues : [Position] = [TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight]
}

let a : NSArray = Position.allValues
```

As fas as I understand Position.allValues is a valid Array, though static. Do I miss something or can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `allValues` is an array *of Position*. But Position is an enum, and a Swift enum can't cross the bridge to Objective-C.

So, yes, `[Int]` or `[String]` will magically cross the bridge to become an NSArray, but not `[Position]` - exactly what the error message told you.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to @matt's answer, since I notice you're using raw values in your enum, you can convert the array of enum cases to an array of strings, by just taking the raw value for each case, and using the `map` method:

```
let a : NSArray = Position.allValues.map { $0.rawValue }
```

Comment: Actually this gives me the error `Position does not have a member named rawValue` in my Playground (after another crash form SourceKit...)

Comment: Are you using Xcode 6.0.x? If yes, then you have to replace `rawValue` with `toRaw()`. If it's not that, can you tell me what's the error?

Comment: Yes, that was it. Very cool! Thanks! Haven't upgraded to 6.1 yet since I am currently on a mobile connection.